# event handler triggered before event occurs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am doing a mega drop down menu whereby a user clicks on an item to display the extension.
I want two results onclick of an item:

1. the extension to be displayed
2. the background color to change for the menu item(the one that is clicked)

but I am having a hard time and both of these results happen before the onclick event occurs.

All other things are so far good below is my code

```
//call the showMenu function to toggle menu items display   
showMenu("#market", "#marketDrop");
showMenu("#jobs", "#jobsDrop");
showMenu("#career", "#careerDrop");
showMenu("#tech", "#techDrop");
showMenu("#estate", "#estateDrop");
showMenu("#fair", "#fairDrop");
showMenu("#leisure", "#leisureDrop");
showMenu("#exclusive", "#exclusiveDrop");

//the showMenu function
function showMenu(listItem, dropDown){
  //first hide the main drop down containers
  $(dropDown).hide();   
  $(listItem).click(function() {
    $(dropDown).fadeToggle();
  });

  $(listItem).click().css("background-color", "#000");      
}
```

Comment: Accept answers that helped you, otherwise people will stop giving answers to your questions

Answer (score 3):

Your last line is *triggering* a click immediately, not *binding* a click handler.

Try this:

```
function showMenu(listItem, dropDown){
    //first hide the main drop down containers
    $(dropDown).hide();   

    // register the click handler
    $(listItem).click(function() {
        $(dropDown).fadeToggle();
        $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
    });
}
```

NB: modern jQuery uses `.on('click', ...)` rather than `.click(...)`.  It helps avoid the confusion with `.click` being used to both trigger and bind handlers, depending on the argument list.  I haven't modified your code to use that just in case you're still on an old version of jQuery.

Comment: thanks big time. i have one more problem. i want it that when i click away from a menu item, those two results are undone: - the background goes away, and the drop down collapses. whether i click on a different menu item, the effects of the previous are undone, or when i click in any other part of the view port. thanks